# APK app build with react-native expo and build with expo stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, eas

I have just finished my first android app using react-native v0.69.6, I have used eas to generate an APK file, which is stuck on the splash screen.
I have also created a new bar-bones project and build an APK file but the same issue.

Comment: Do you remember if you resolved this? Can you please share? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There could be hundred of reasons why it's stuck there.

First of all make sure to read carefully all the doc: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/

If still doesn't work, try to add Sentry to your Expo app, so you can catch some errors that may be blocking it. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/

Comment: thank you for your respone, I have created a bare-bone app and used expo build:android and works just fine I think it's eas issue.